# Swift 2: Can't find audio file path when I use variables as file names

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer, nsurl

Here's a very strange phenomenon that I'm struggling with:

I'm trying to play an audio file on a button click based on a certain context. For instance if the condition "A" I'll play a certain sound (on button click) and if it is "B" I'd play another sound. I use a switch statement to decide what sounds are played for which condition.

The problem: Even though I'm getting the conditions to work correctly, the AVAudioPlayer always returns nil. But when I hard-code the file to be played, it works just fine. It is only when I use a variable to decide which sound to be played "in the switch statement" is when the sound doesn't play, else when I use a static variable without changing its value, it works fine.

Here's my code:

```
func playSound(Condition: String){

    switch Condition {
    case "1":
        soundName = "1"
    case "2":
        soundName = "2"
    case "3":
        soundName = "3"
    case "4":
        soundName = "4"
    case "5":
        soundName = "5"
    default:
        soundName = "default"
    }

  let pathString = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(soundName, withExtension: "m4a")?.path //if I type 'let soundName = "1" or Hard code the value' - it will work fine

    if let soundFilePath = pathString {
        let sound = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundFilePath)

        do{
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:sound)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        }catch {
            print("Error getting the audio file")
        }
    } else {
        print("Error: Can't find file. Path is nil") // - This is always printed when I use the variable result from the switch
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me figure out why? Is the switch taking too long? I doubt because I can print the value of the condition before I play the sound. Thanks in advance.

Added More Information Here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/137380#137380

Comment: please give more code context, such as where `playSound(condition:)` is being called.

Comment: it is called when a button is clicked. The condition is supplied depending on factors such as what day is it, what time is it, etc.

Comment: Okay, wait, are both parts you pasted part of the `playSound(condition:)` function?

Comment: Yes, that's one function. So .. there's a button on the UI when pressed this function is called that plays a sound depending on say what time it is.

Comment: There you go, I corrected the formatting. It now appears as a single block of code - one function.

Comment: Are you sure soundName is not changed somewhere else as it appears to be a global variable? In my quick test in a playground, you're code should be fine. Here's the playground code: http://pastebin.com/Ztc5gnH7

Comment: Put a break point in at the first line of the function and step through it. What's the value of `condition`? Then what's the value of `soundName`?

Comment: No the value of SoundName is not changed anywhere else.

Comment: Value of condition is correct, just as expected each time.

Comment: just checked again: soundName is correct, as expected, whereas 

let pathString = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(soundName, withExtension: "m4a")?.path

results in nil if I use soundName from the switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work. I guess the problem was with the files. Re-did everything and now its working. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare soundName

I.e.

```
func playSound(Condition: String){

var soundName: String

switch Condition {
case "1":
    soundName = "1"
case "2":
    soundName = "2"
case "3":
    soundName = "3"
case "4":
    soundName = "4"
case "5":
    soundName = "5"
default:
    soundName = "default"
}
```

let pathString = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(soundName, withExtension: "m4a")?.path //if I type 'let soundName = "1" or Hard code the value' - it will work fine

```
if let soundFilePath = pathString {
    let sound = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundFilePath)

    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:sound)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }catch {
        print("Error getting the audio file")
    }
} else {
    print("Error: Can't find file. Path is nil") // - This is always printed when I use the variable result from the switch
}
```

Comment: soundName is declared outside the function ... even if I declare it inside, it still doesn't work